# Valid XML or not

Tags: xml

Please see the sample xml given below. As per a requirement, I need to have a similar structure. Could someone verify if this is valid XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
   <name>name1</name>
   <price>price1</price>
</book>
<book>
   <name>name2</name>
   <price>price2</price>
</book>
<book>
   <name>name3</name>
   <price>price3</price>
</book>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't.

An XML document must have a single root element.

i.e. the element you open first must be the element you close last.

The first element you open is `book` on line 2. You close it on line 5. On line 6 you open *another* `book`.

You probably want to wrap all the `book` elements with a `books` element or a `library` element.

Comment: @Marcin —  It is true: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-root The document entity is not the root element.

Answer (score 2):

It is not valid, you need a root tag to encompass the rest of your tags

something like this makes more sense:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Books>   
    <book>
        <name>name1</name>
        <price>price1</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>name2</name>
        <price>price2</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>name3</name>
        <price>price3</price>
    </book>
</Books>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the validator on : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Your xml will not vallidate becauese you have more then 1 root element.

something like the following will:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <catalog>
        <book>
            <name>name1</name>
            <price>price1</price>
       </book>
       <book>
            <name>name2</name>
            <price>price2</price>
       </book>
       <book>
            <name>name3</name>
            <price>price3</price>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```